# Taking columns of different type as training dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, text-classification

I earlier worked on taking just one column(string type data) as my train set, I would like to take another corresponding column(Amount column of float type) into consideration as a train set along with the Details column.
In the amount column negative value indicates debit and positive value indicates credit.
How do I proceed with this, I tried appending two columns together but I
had to convert the float type amount to  string type which doesn't make
any sense in my dataset.
I want to include the Amount column to check if the machine could learn the variations, which is quite important in this case.
Thanks in advance.

```
Details                    |Amount               |Category
-------------------------------------------------------------                                
Tanishq Jwellery Bangalore |-990                 |jwellery
ODESK***BAL-28APR13        |240                  |Others
AEGON RELIGARE LIFE IN     |456                  |Others
INTERNET PAYMENT #999999   |-250                 |Transfer in for Card Payment
WWW.VISTAPRINT.IN          |245                  |Print
Khazana Jwellery           |-9000                |jwellery
INTERNET PAYMENT #999999   |785                  |Transfer in for Card Payment
Indian Oil                 |344                  |Fuel
Touch foot wear            |-782                 |Clothing
```

Part of my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

# TRAIN DATA
data= pd.read_csv('ds1.csv', delimiter=',',usecols=['Details','Amount','Category'],encoding='utf-8')
data=data[data.Category !="Others"]

target_one=data['Category']
target_list=data['Category'].unique()

# TEST DATASET
test_data=pd.read_csv('ds2.csv', delimiter='\t',usecols=['Details','Amount','Category'],encoding='utf-8')

x_train, y_train = (data.Details, data.Category )
x_test, y_test = (test_data.Details, test_data.Category)

vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
X_train = vect.fit_transform(x_train)

X_test = vect.transform(x_test)
start = time.clock()

mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha =0.13)
mnb.fit(X_train,y_train)

result= mnb.predict(X_test)
print (time.clock()-start)

accuracy_score(result,y_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to stack the "amount" column to the matrix of text fetaures obtained with the `CountVectorizer`, just do this before fitting the `MultinomialNB`:

```
import numpy as np

X_amount = data["Amount"].as_matrix().reshape(-1, 1)
X_train = X_train.toarray()
X_train = np.hstack((X_train, X_amount))
X_test_amount = test_data["Amount"].as_matrix().reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.toarray()
X_test = np.hstack((X_test, X_test_amount))
```

OR if you want to keep dealing with sparse matrix for X_train :

```
import scipy as sp

X_amount = data["Amount"].as_matrix().reshape(-1, 1)
X_train = sp.sparse.hstack((X_train, X_amount))
X_test_amount = test_data["Amount"].as_matrix().reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = sp.sparse.hstack((X_test, X_test_amount))
```

But then, I think you will end up with `ValueError: Input X must be non-negative`, because `MultinomialNB` is intended for use with non-negative feature values...

Comment: Thanks @arthur, but I'm getting an error like:                                                         ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.( when tried to fit it with the classifier)

Comment: @Vichu oh yes sorry, it's because X_train given by the vectorizer is in sparse format see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot @arthur , sorry another problem , there is a memory error when I convert  countvectorised output to array (X_train.toarray()

Comment: @Vichu then keep dealing with sparse matrix (second option in my answer).

Comment: Thanks @arthur, porbably I have to try changing the classifier as MNB cant handle negative values.